# Is client javascript injection detectable for server?

Tags: javascript-injection

I am developing a web-scraper on an Android App and I have developed automated surfing with js insertion. I do tasks like the following:

```
document.getElementById("user").innerText="userName";
document.getElementById("pass").innerText="pass";
document.getElementById("submit").click();
```

I would like to know if this code is in any way detectable by the server. If so, is there any way to avoid being detected?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like conceptually the way various password managers insert credentials.

While it might of course be possible to check this (e.g. inserting without focus on the input element) and notify the server. There should normally be no reason to prevent the client from doing that.

Comment: But how could I see if that info (not focused submits) is sent to the server??

Comment: Now this is becoming hypothetical. But to see outgoing javascript requests you would have to intercept these requests, probably based on the fetch api or XMLHttpRequest. Modifying natives is a bad approach though.